# What is the difference between the usages of bis-tris methane and bis-tris propane?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-reagents

I came across "bis-tris" buffer in Rodney Boyer's *Biochemistry Laboratory* book and tried looking it up. Then I found that there's bis-tris methane and bis-tris propane that are both buffers. What exactly are they used for and are the usages different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have different acid dissociation equilibria and so buffer at different pH.

```
                    pKa1    pKa2
Bis-Tris methane    6.5     -
Bis-Tris propane    6.8     9
```

[[source](http://medicine.ucsf.edu/labs/brown/sigma_buffer_chart.pdf)]

The two titratable secondary amines of Bis-Tris propane make it usable over a wider pH range.